# Installation Of Microsoft Visual Studio in XP fails

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Despite having installed Microsoft windows xp service pack 3(upgraded from SP-2) the installation of Visual Studio was not successful!

The log says

Blocking Components exist and must be satisified before continuing to install [01/02/07,10:41:18] VS Scenario: [2] Windows XP Service Pack 3 is required [01/02/07,10:41:19] VS Scenario: [2] End of Blocking Component List * [

What may be the problem?:

Comment: Folks, after a very long search adventure I came up with the following solution. It now installed successfully..

  1) Remove ServicePack 3 from control panel and re-installed it.
  2) Installed a separate downloaded file of Microsoft Installer @4.5
  3) Made sure that adequate space is available in C: drive or whatever disk is your primary partition.

Comment: @Windows displays ;Windows xp service pack 3 is required despite having it installed already! Problem with that error message :)P It turned out to be because of the installer version that should be 4.5